# 2 byte format string attacks

Tags: disassembly, c, buffer-overflow, address

**Protostar**

I was doing the protostar format string (3rd challenge). where we have to change the value of a variable target with format string buffer overflow. so, I came up to this medium  article: [HERE](https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/expdev-exploit-exercise-protostar-format-3-33e8d8f1e83)

So, he has described three types of attacks. the second and third ones seem hard to understand.

**2 byte**

I want to know that he has divided the target value (0x00000000) into 2 bytes (0000) in the second method. it means that we are splitting the values into two bytes. am I right? and if I am right what is the thing he did for getting the second address of the target(0x80496f6). how could he possibly get that from the real address (0x80496f4)? all I can understand is he might have subtracted 0x2 from the real address(0x80496f4).
Does the value of the target stores into two addresses?
His command is :

```
python -c 'print "\xf4\x96\x04\x08" + "\xf6\x96\x04\x08" + "%13$hn" + "%12$hn"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and third methods are simply variants of the first method, using different write sizes.

The `%n` format specifier writes 4 bytes to the destination address. There are times where you may not want to write this many bytes as once; maybe you only want to partially overwrite a value, or more importantly, it may be too slow this way. Let's say you wanted to write the value 0xdeadbeef; in this particular case, the program has to print out 3,735,928,559 characters, which can take a while to write. It is often quicker to do several smaller writes instead of one huge write. So, the specifier can be used with a length modifier to change the number of bytes written. `%hn` is 2 bytes, and `%hhn` is one byte.

So, you can break the problem into two chunks. Let's use the address from your example, 0x80496f4, as the target where we want to write. The first 2 bytes (little endian, 0xefbe) can be written at 0x80496f4 with an `%hn`. Since we're going 2 bytes at a time, the next write needs to be at 0x80496f4+2, which is where 0x80496f6 comes from. Here, the next two bytes can be written with `%hn`, 0xadde.

Or, you can do it in 4 chunks by doing single-byte writes.

Comment: but why the address 0x80496f6 is assigned to target? is it not assigned to some other instruction?

Comment: No, on a 32-bit system, data is typically 4 bytes. So for data that starts at 0x80496f4, 0x80496f6 would be the "middle" of that data. It may help to hook up a debugger and look around some.

Comment: And I don't know if I should ask it but did you see what he did when was he getting minus in result? why was he adding "1" before the hex address?

Comment: If you are only able to write one byte, there's no difference between writing 0x101 and 0x01, or 0x5544 and 0x44.

Comment: I don't know if I am frustrating but I didn't understand it.

Comment: If you are only writing one byte, any value larger than that will always be `n % 256` or `n & 0x000000ff` since only the least significant byte will fit. Try that in code or a calculator.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some resources where you learnt it from?

Comment: Learned them from many places over the years, plenty of online resources. Never fully understood/felt confident until I exploited in the wild.

Comment: Can I follow you? here's my discord: luckythandel#6053